# How to write a sequence of conditions in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I want to plot a circle or any signal when a sequence of conditions happen. There are 4 possible conditions: A, B, C and nothing. I want to send a signal when the sequence A,B,A or B,A,B are true, but not when there is a C in between (i.e: A,C,B,A). Also, after any step of the sequence can be "nothing", so the last condition (A, B or C) is hold.

Being more specific, I want to detect when the MACD and Signal lines make one cross over the 0 line (A), then another cross below it (B), and then a cross over 0 again (0). But I want to discard any additional crossings that may happen in between. The idea is to analyize when this sort of sinewave in the MACD happens.

I figured out on how to represent it with colors, so it is more easy to see a RED-GREEN-RED pattern or a GREEN-RED-GREEN. The GREY color restarts everything.

I don't have any clue on how to start defining a sequence of conditions or events in Pine. Can anyone help me with which parameters should I study to define a sequence?

Thank you

[RED-GREEN-RED sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WozZn.jpg)

```
// Getting inputs
fast_length = input(title='Fast Length', defval=12)
slow_length = input(title='Slow Length', defval=26)
src = input(title='Source', defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title='Signal Smoothing', minval=1, maxval=50, defval=9)
sma_source = input(title='Simple MA(Oscillator)', defval=false)
sma_signal = input(title='Simple MA(Signal Line)', defval=false)


// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal



//Adding MACD Crossings Up and Down 

crossover_1 = ta.crossover(signal, macd)
xUp = macd > 0 ? crossover_1 : na
crossunder_1 = ta.crossunder(signal, macd)
xDn = macd < 0 ? crossunder_1 : na
crossunder_2 = ta.crossunder(signal, macd)
xDnHigh = macd >= 0 ? crossunder_2 : na
crossover_2 = ta.crossover(signal, macd)
xUpLow = macd <= 0 ? crossover_2 : na
wrongs = xUpLow or xDnHigh


sinewavecolor = color.white
sinewavecolor := xDn ? color.green : xUp ? color.red : wrongs ? color.gray : sinewavecolor[1]
bgcolor(sinewavecolor)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a state machine.

Let's take have a look at `A,B,A` with the condition that `C` would reset things.

You need to define your states first:

```
STATE_NONE = 0
STATE_1 = 1  // A
STATE_2 = 2  // B
STATE_3 = 3  // A

var current_state = STATE_NONE

if (current_state == STATE_NONE)
    if (condition_A)
        current_state := STATE_1     // Go to next state
else if (current_state == STATE_1)
    if (condition_C)
        current_state := STATE_NONE  // Reset
    else if (condition_B)
        current_state := STATE_2     // Go to next state
else if (current_state == STATE_2)
    if (condition_C)
        current_state := STATE_NONE  // Reset
    else if (condition_A)
        current_state := STATE_3     // Go to next state
else if (current_state == STATE_3)
    // alert or do whatever you want to do
    current_state := STATE_NONE      // Go back to initial state to detect the next sequence
```

Comment: This seems to work. I will exlpore all the options, thank you!